# slurm script gives "command not found"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cluster-computing, slurm

I am trying to submit a script to slurm that runs m4 on an input file.  m4 is installed on our cluster, and if I run the script by itself, everything works as expected.  But when I submit a run to slurm via a slurm script, I get an error.

Here is the script I would like to run (named m4it.sh).
[Note that I'm printing PATH and SHELL in an attempt to debug.]

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Beginning m4it.sh"
echo "PATH=$PATH"
echo "SHELL=$SHELL"
echo

m4 file.m4 > fileout.txt
```

and here is my slurm script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=m4it

### Account name (req'd)
#SBATCH --account=MyAccount

### Redirect .o and .e files to the logs dir
#SBATCH -o m4it.out
#SBATCH -e m4it.err
#
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --time=00:01:00
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=125

echo "PATH=$PATH"
echo "SHELL=$SHELL"
echo 
echo "running m4it.sh"
echo
./m4it.sh
```

which submits successfully to slurm via

```
sbatch m4it.slurm
```

When it executes, I get the following error in my m4it.err logfile:

```
./m4it.sh: line 8: m4: command not found
```

The PATH and the SHELL variables (printed to m4it.out by the m4it.slurm and by the m4it.sh scripts) are identical.  The PATH contains my PATH when I login, and SHELL is /bin/bash, as expected.

Even if I include a symlink to the m4 executable from a directory in my PATH, I still get this error.  Also, it is not just m4 that is the problem.  The script will report the command "apropos" as an unknown command, even though it runs fine on the command line.  The script can "cd" and "ls" just fine though.

I've checked read/write/execute permissions.

```
ls -ld / /usr /usr/bin /usr/bin/m4
```

yields the following:

```
dr-xr-xr-x. 30 root root   4096 Apr  8 11:11 /
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root root   4096 Feb 17 20:24 /usr
dr-xr-xr-x.  2 root root  36864 Apr 29 11:14 /usr/bin
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 212440 Jun  3  2010 /usr/bin/m4
```

It seems that the node the m4it.sh script executes on is different from the front node and that somehow information (environment variables or paths) are not coming across.  I have also tried to export all my settings with the argument --export=ALL as follows:

```
sbatch m4it.slurm --export=ALL
```

but this didn't work either (same result).
Can anyone help here?

Comment: What's output of `which m4`?

Comment: At the command line, "which m4" returns /usr/bin/m4.  I added "which m4" to both the .sh and .slurm scripts. I get nothing back in the .out file. In the .err file, it says "which: no m4 in (/....all of the directories in my PATH.../)  What's strange is that /usr/bin is in my PATH.  And so is the directory where I put a symlink to m4.

Comment: Which user runs m4it.sh? Please add output of `ls -ld / /usr /usr/bin /usr/bin/m4` to your question.

Comment: The output to the ls is added above in the question.  I am not sure who executes m4it.sh, but I'm guessing it is the slurm daemon the interprets the m4it.slurm script.

Comment: Try running the ls command inside the job. It seems like m4 is not installed in the compute nodes where your job is running.

Comment: @CarlesFenoy Yes, the "ls" command works fine in the script. Perhaps the compute node doesn't have m4 installed, but my PATH variable includes paths both to /usr/bin/ and to a bin directory in my home (home/mvincent/bin) which also includes a symlink to m4.

Comment: @MadeleineP.Vincent I meant, run `ls -ld / /usr /usr/bin /usr/bin/m4` in the job script and add the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to log in to the compute node in an interactive session.  Indeed that node's /usr/bin is significantly different than the front node's, and m4 is not installed.

This also explains why the symlink from a directory in my PATH no longer worked. It was pointing to /usr/bin/m4, but as soon as the job was executed on that compute node, /usr/bin/m4 no longer existed, and thus the symlink was invalid.

If I want to use m4, the solution is to either ask the admins to install m4 on the compute nodes or, alternatively, copy a local version of the executable to somewhere in my home directory that exists in my PATH variable.